# Open an iframe containing XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

```
var iframe = $('#auditframe').get(0).contentWindow;

iframe.document.open("text/xml", "replace");
iframe.document.write(xml);
```

This works. My iframe gets populated with a valid xml string. But is there any way to open the iframe in a new window? I want the user to see  the XML document that has been added to the frame. Is there any way to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar technique, except you open a blank window, create a new document in the window, and then write the content you want. See this fiddle for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2v3Gr/

Comment: If i check the source on the popup, its valid xml, but IE still doesnt show it as an XML, just a text string. Is there any thing to to about that?

Comment: IE apparently ignores the MIME type specified when you open the document and just assumes it's HTML. Not sure what to do about that except to open the window to a URL that actually sends down XML.